# VBA: Download Excel file from https://chartink.com/screener/practical-swing-trading-stock-scanner

Tags: excel, vba

I want to mention it before hand that I have extremely basic knowledge of programming. I want to download a Excel file from https://chartink.com/screener/practical-swing-trading-stock-scanner. Manually it is done by clicking on a button labeled "Excel". Upon examining the webpage code in web developer tool, I found that the click event is handled by a javascript file titled "atlas.js". I am clueless about how to begin. I want to download the excel file and then copy the contents of this file to a local excel file on my computer.

Following code send a http request to the chartink website. I have noticed that  objHttpRequest.ResponseText containts code which is different from the one which displays in the web developer tool of mozilla firefox.

```
    Dim objHttpRequest As Object
    Set objHttpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    
    objHttpRequest.Open "GET", "https://chartink.com/screener/practical-swing-trading-stock-scanner", False
    objHttpRequest.SetRequestHeader "REFERER", "https://chartink.com/"
    objHttpRequest.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
    
    objHttpRequest.Send
    
    Debug.Print objHttpRequest.ResponseText
```

Comment: I did a GET request at the website and from what I can see, the data is loaded into the browser, meaning that web page returns addresses for each set of data, and doesn't contain any data itself. You would need to tell the browser to load the page and then use the button. Selenium VBA would help accomplish that.

Comment: Are you suggesting to open the webpage using the internet explorer object and  trigger the button click event? If yes then how do I capture the excel file that downloads upon clicking the button? I have to copy the data from the downloaded file to another excel file. Thanks